# HP UFT: XML Attributes are missing from Spreadsheet generated from XML

Tags: xml, hp-uft, uft-api

I have an Acord Schema XML that makes heavy use of Attributes.  For example:

```
<Person id="Party_1">
    <Name>John Doe</Name>
    <Age>31</Age>
</Person>
```

When I use UFT to "Data Drive" this (generate a data spreadsheet from my example XML), I get a spreadsheet that contains only the elements that have text values, and it is missing all Attributes.

For example, the above XML would produce the following columns in the spreadsheet:

```
Name     | Age
John Doe | 31
```

I expect it should do something like:

```
Party@id | Name     | Age
Party_1  | John Doe | 31
```

Why doesn't it give a column and value for Party@id ?

Here are some specific images:

[image: 1. notice attributes PrimaryObjectID and tc]
[image: 2. notice those attributes are not in the generated spreadsheet]

Comment: How are you generating spreadsheet from XML?

Comment: @ManishChristian Testing a SOAP service, paste in XML text, then "Data Drive Entire Step" feature

Comment: I am still not getting how your SS is getting generated. Could you add some more info? May be screenshot?

Comment: @ManishChristian I've added some screenshots